# Rewriting memory allocated via cudaHostAlloc()

Tags: cuda

I have a 100MB character array (`h_array`) that is allocated using `cudaHostAlloc()` with the flag `cudaHostAllocWriteCombined`.

The program first copies data into `h_array` on the host. When `h_array` is full, it will copy `h_array` to `d_array` on the device and some processing is done. When the processing is completed, `h_array` is *reused* in the sense that new data is copied to it again, starting from `h_array[0]`. The new data is meant to overwrite what was previously stored in `h_array`.

However, I'm getting segmentation fault when the new data is copied to `h_array` after processing is complete. There are no seg fault errors when I'm using regular `malloc`.

What is wrong? Can I not rewrite the memory when it's pinned?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you wrapped all your CUDA runtime calls with cudaSafeCall and used cudaCheckError after your kernel calls? That point to a problem much before your segmentation fault.

Comment: You should be able to do that. Could you reduce your code size to exemplify your problem and show it to us? Usually the problem lies in the details...

Answer (score 1):

Your CUDA context is probably getting yanked out from under you somehow.

For example, if you allocate the pinned host memory in a thread that then exits, the memory will go away.

Make sure the thread that performs the allocation sticks around!